# How to float right image below one line content

Tags: css, css-float

This is my content
[image: My content]

How ideas to image float right content below 1 line
[image: My content 2]

This is my code

```
<div class="single-content">
   <div class="floating-image-right">
       <img src="https://dl2.macupdate.com/images/icons256/30017.png" />
   </div>
   <div class="entry_content">
<strong>CleanMyMac</strong> makes space for the things you love. Sporting a range of ingenious new features, CleanMyMac lets you safely and intelligently scan and clean your entire system, delete large, unused files, reduce the size of your iPhoto library, uninstall unneeded apps or fix the ones that started to work improperly, manage all your extensions from one place and do much more – all from one newly designed and beautifully simple interface.
   </div>
</div>

<style>
.floating-image-right {
    float: right;
    max-width: 128px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to be really specific where you place your `floating-image-right` tag.

https://jsfiddle.net/fgpLs4u5/2/

```css
body {
  max-width:800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
span.img-demo {
  background: red;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  float: right;
  margin: 7px 0 10px 10px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<p class="content">
 This is some content here. This is some content here. This is some content here. This is some content here. <span class="img-demo"></span> This is some content here. This is some content here. This is some content here. This is some content here. This is some content here. This is some content here. This is some content here. This is some content here. This is some content here. This is some content here. This is some content here. This is some content here. This is some content here. This is some content here. This is some content here. This is some content here. This is some content here. This is some content here. This is some content here. This is some content here. 
</p>
```